# Print 8 digits after dot

Tags: printing

I have this number:

```
$total = '0.04149951583898188';
```

I want to diplay only the first 8 digits after the dot, like this: `0.0414995`

How can I do this?

Comment: You didn't even specify a target language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, guessing from your profile & the code snippet that you’re probably talking about PHP. Do not forget to tell us which language you want help with, we shouldn’t have to guess!

Have a look at PHP’s [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function:

```
<?php
$total = '0.04149951583898188';
echo round((float)$total, 8); // Cast the $total string variable to a type float, and round it
?>
```